# File appears on a huge delay when using Export

Tags: export

When I use the Export function, even for simple things such as

```
Export["Plot.png", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}]];
```

there's a considerable delay after execution stops and before the file actually shows up in the directory. Sometimes the delay is as little as 5 seconds, at other times it's as long as three minutes.

I use 11.2 on High Sierra and this started happening on all of my Macs recently. I upgraded to 11.2 and High Sierra at about the same time.

Could this be a Mathematica issue? Is it more likely to be the OS?

Comment: I've noticed similar delays, but for me they clearly started only after upgrading to High Sierra. I think it's an OS problem. For example, I also noticed significant slowdown in moving a large number of files to the Trash all at once in the Finder. Weirdly, I can't reproduce it currently. Maybe this delay is related to some new indexing that only takes place once after the upgrade (would explain why I don't see it now). If you can still see the problem, maybe try to do `ls` in the Terminal to see if that reacts faster after new files are created.

Comment: Thanks, Jens. I'll try this: http://ashley-cameron.com/blog/macos-high-sierra-bug-fix-desktop-finder-delay-showing-files/